# Multi image support for EZ Platform

Tags: ezplatform

I am trying to find out how to create a field definition with a dynamic multi image support. The image field type in ezplatform doesn't support dynamic multi images. I will appreciate even creating a custom a field.Any ideas?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by multi-image ? can you just explain your use case maybe that way I can help!

Comment: Thank you Amir, the form image type in the content field definition only allows an image file field that can upload only a single image, how do I achieve multiple "many" files upload for the image field.

Comment: I see what you mean now. NO, we do not have such a thing in ez. but why not multiple image attributes instead of multiple images in one attribute ? I do not know your exact use-case but you can achieve anything you want with that. for example image slider, Image gallery and .......

Comment: Yes Amir, thank you for clarifying that. My use case is Image gallery where the user doesn't know the number of images and it will be different numbers in each content instance. I will store the images in a textarea using WYSIWYG then iterate over the field to retrieve the images. Am I correct to assume that you meant creating multiple instances of the image field "attribute" but won't that require fixing the number of attributes?  I am new to EZPlatform, so far so good.

Comment: I see! yes, that's true. with multiple attributes, you should define a fix number. I have another solution for you I will write as answer so when it was correct you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for calrification and telling more about your Use-Case.

you can use `object-relations` attribute for the purpose of image gallery and iterate over all related objects to that field and display them. your user should just relate `image` objects.

in that way the user can relate as many image object as he/she wants from Media Library.

Comment: I will try this one.

Comment: did that help you? if yes, mark the question as solved please!

Comment: Thanks Amir, that was very helpful